# Вопросы по ООП в C++

Tags: c++, память, стек, деструктор, выделение-памяти

Я недавно начал изучать ООП. И возникло ряд вопросов.

1.После выполнения деструктора как я понимаю происходит отчистка полей-членов класса. То есть если я правильно понимаю, то после выполнения первого деструктора объекта object освобождается память выделенная на стеке(в данном случае это int A). То что происходит после выполнения деструктора второй раз. Будет UB?

```
#include <iostream>

class Alpha{
public:
  int A;
  Alpha(){}
  ~Alpha(){}
};

int main(){
  Alpha object;
  object.~Alpha();
  object.~Alpha();
}
```

2.Что будет если вызвать явно деструктор для динамически выделенного объекта класса object. Будет ли освобождена память, которую занимают поля-члены(в данном случае - int A)? Ведь (int A) будет выделена на куче. Я думаю, что память не будет освобождена. Но тогда получается, что после выполнения деструктора может освобождаться память только для полей-членов, которые были выделены на стеке.

```
#include <iostream>

class Alpha{
public:
  int A;
  Alpha(){}
  ~Alpha(){}
};

int main(){
  Alpha* object = new Alpha;
  object->~Alpha();
}
```

3.Почему для класса Bion деструктор вызывается один раз. А для класса Alpha деструктор вызывается два раза.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Alpha{
public:
  int A;
  Alpha(){}
  ~Alpha(){cout << "~Alpha" << '\n';}
};

class Bion{
public:
  int B;
  Bion(){}
  ~Bion(){cout << "~Bion" << '\n';}
};

int main(){
  Alpha object_alpha;
  Bion* object_bion = new Bion;
  delete object_bion;
  object_alpha.~Alpha();
}

вывод:
      ~Bion
      ~Alpha
      ~Alpha
```

Comment: Деструктор явно вызывать не требуется. По крайней мере, в 99.99% случаев. Вы показываете, как **не** надо делать. Деструктор вызывается *автоматически*. Вот потому у вас и два вызова деструктора в последнем коде.

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, в стандарте ведь нет запрета на несколько вызовов, если объект оставлен в подходящем для этого состоянии?

Comment: После того, как вызван деструктор, объект считается мертвым и Применять для него какие то функции не стоит, в том числе деструктор.  У автора для объекта Alpha вызывается два раза вручную деструктр, а потом оно же автоматом. Это прям выстрел в ухо

Comment: @Qwertiy Плохие привычки обычно приводят к плохим последствиям... Я же не написал "категорически нельзя", я даже оставил 0.01% :)

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, я ж не про это. Вроде есть случаи, когда надо явно вызывать. Но я про другое: вот в вопросе код с 3 вызовами пустого деструктора на одном объекте - это UB или не UB? Можно ли примерно так же как move сказать, что если деструктор написан таким образом, что он оставляет объект в валидном состоянии, то его вызывать несколько раз можно? Или в любой ситуации повторный вызов является UB?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не скажу точно. Но приучен к "пока конструктор не завершился - объекта еще нет; когда деструктор завершился - объекта уже нет". Если класс является наследником наследника еще кого-то там... вы сможете гарантировать, что объект остается в валидном состоянии?

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, не знаю))) Но вдруг смогу?)) Но не знаю, зачем) А любопытно всё равно xD

Answer (score 5):

1. Деструктор не освобождает память, которую занимает объект. Ваш деструктор не делает вообще ничего, в том смысле что он компилируется в 0 инструкций.

   Однако, стандарт говорит, что деструктор "заканчивает время жизни объекта" ([`[basic.life]/1.4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.4)). Это формальность, в том смысле, что глядя на байты в памяти нельзя определить, жив объект или мертв. Но вызов деструктора (или любого метода) второй раз на нем же вызывает UB. Причем даже если написать `object.~Alpha();` один раз (а не два), UB все равно будет, потому что при уничтожении переменной деструктор вызывается автоматически (т.е. еще один раз).
2. Память останется выделенной. И ваш деструктор ничего не делает. Единственный эффект - формальное окончание времени жизни объекта.

   > получается, что после выполнения деструктора может освобождаться память только для полей-членов, которые были выделены на стеке

   Вот это вообще не понял. Память под поля освобождается, когда освобождается память под весь объект. Деструктор этого не делает.
3. См. (1).

Answer (score 3):

1. Деструктор не освобождает память.
2. Деструктор вызывается автоматически в конце области видимости локальной переменной с объектом. А так же, при использовании `delete`.
3. Явно вызывать деструктор не надо. <s>Кроме деструктора базового класса в деструкторе дочернего.</s>
4. В твоём коде деструктор ничего не делает, так что его можно безвредно вызывать сколько угодно, как и любой обычный метод. По крайней мере, я так думаю, но могу и ошибаться.

Comment: *"Кроме деструктора базового класса в деструкторе дочернего."* Мм? Он сам вызывается.

Comment: @Qwertiy, То есть как я понял. Конструктор это особый метод класса, который просто вызывается перед высвобождением памяти, которая была выделена под объект класса. А когда мы просто его вызываем, например в функции main, то он просто вызывается как обычный метод и ничего не разрушает и не высвобождает память. А уже после выхода из функции(в конце области видимости данного объекта) ещё раз вызывается деструктор и уже теперь высвобождается память. Я прав?

Comment: По пункту 3 - *Кроме деструктора базового класса в деструкторе дочернего* - с этого места подробнее, pls...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, кажется, я что-то не то ляпнул...

Answer (score 1):

- Память не освобождается, потому что вызван деструктор, а деструктор
  вызывается при уничтожении объекта. Раз объекта нет, значит память
  свободна.
- Если объект владеет некоторым участком памяти, тогда его деструктор
  должен освобождать эту память или это нужно сделать в ручную, но
  **перед уничтожением** объекта:
- Но бывают случаи, когда деструктор ничего не делает или не делает
  ничего, связанное с некоторым участком памяти.

Можно написать маленький пример для демонстрации:

```
    struct A {
        ~A() { cout << "  object destroyed\n"; }
    };
    int main()
    {   
        int k = 1;
        cout << k;
        //некоторая область видимости, после чего объект
        //уничтожается, "говоря последнее слово перед смертью"
        // _ вызов деструктора
        {
            A a;
        }
        // объекта "а" не существует
        // при уничтожении объекта вызывается его деструктор        
        A a1;
        cout << k + sizeof(A) << "-nd "; 
        // при возвращении из функции и "a1" уничтожен
        //(как и все статические) объекты соответственно
        //вызваны деструкторы, и память освобождена
        return 0;
    }
```

- Также бывают случаи, что деструктору не нужно освобождать память, так
  как объект не владеет никаким участком памяти, но деструктор может
  выполнить не менее важные функции, такие, как:

**закрытие файла,** **возвращение начального состояния(флагов)**, **установка старой функции завершения программы**(std::terminate_handler) и т.д. и т.п.

Поэтому, с точки зрения стандарта,

> " Как только для объекта вызывается деструктор, этот объект больше не
> существует"

. А значит,  это есть общее допущение, не зависимое от состояния объекта, что если вызван деструктор,  приложение может считать, что этого объекта нет _ игнорировать его, даже если он есть на самом деле.  И опять же по стандарту(и по логике языка):

> "поведение не определено, если деструктор вызывается для объекта,
> время жизни которого закончилось "

.А значит, в любом случаи, повторный вызов деструктора может закончится одним словом _ "Бум!"...
**Не делайте так**, если хотите избегать проблем.